# unable to execute statements in sequential order while calling one function from another function in javascript

Tags: javascript

while designing my webpage, i have done with some javascript validations, in JS file, i'm trying to call one function from another function. The first is called when i click on button. In first function, i'm trying to set text for label and then i called the second function, but the second function is called first and then the text is set for label. The sequence is missing. I don't know, why the statements are not executed in sequence...If anyone know, please tell me the solution.

```
<script>
    function first(){
        labelValue = document.getElementById("getlabel");
        labelValue.innerHTML = "FirstText";
        second();
    }
    function second(){
        labelValue.text = "secondText";
    }
```

Here, i can't set text for 'labelValue' i.e., "FirstText" before second() is called. It was set after second() is called.

```
function first(){
    labelValue = document.getElementById("getlabel");
    labelValue.innerHTML = "FirstText";
    image = document.getElementById("getImage");
    image.src = "hello.jpg";
    second();  
}
function second(){
    labelValue.innerHTML = "SecondText";
    label1 = document.getElementById("name");
    label1.innerHTML =  "sarah";
}
```

first it sets value for 'name' label and then it sets image 'hello.jpg' for 'image' and the text 'FirstText' for label 'labelValue'.

Comment: Consider preparing a http://jsfiddle.net demo

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `second()` you are setting `labelValue.text`. You should be setting `labelValue.innerHTML`, that is why it doesn't update the content and makes you think they aren't executed sequentially.

Edit: The updated code you posted works, you're going to have to give us the Javascript and HTML that replicates the problem. See my updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5zce/).

Comment: I tried with labelValue.innerHTML only even i can't set value to label . In  second() also, there are some statements, after executing all those statements, it sets the label text, that is my problem..

Comment: So the code you posted isn't the actual code then? Post the actual code.